# Database.Migrate method

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i want to apply migrations automatically for my app
so i used this method

Database.Migrate()

Applies any pending migrations for the context to the database. Will create the database if it does not already exist.

so as i understood when i run my application it should do as follow
1- create database if it doesn't exist
2- update database => apply migration to database

but when I run my project nothing happens
i write command manually to apply database and it's work but i don't know where is the problem

this is my code

dbContext

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using brokerTest.Entites;

namespace brokerTest.Brokers.Sotrage
{
    public class StorageBroker : DbContext , IStorageBroker
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
        public StorageBroker(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.configuration = configuration;
            this.Database.Migrate();
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder){

            var connectionString = this.configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<StorageBroker>();
            services.AddScoped<IStorageBroker, StorageBroker>();
```

appsettingfile.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=testDb"
  },
```

Package installed
.NET 6 , Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 5.0.8
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 5.0.8

Comment: Your question has little to do with ASP.Net. I suggest you tag it with an appropriate version of Entity Framework.

Comment: [Apply migrations at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#apply-migrations-at-runtime)

Comment: @Sasan can i do that in dbContext class i made ? 
like above code and what's wrong with my code if any

Comment: The constructor will be run every time a new DbContext is created. Applying production migrations is something that needs careful strategy (or there is a chance of data loss or worse program crash). Even Microsoft Docs doesn't recommend this but if you need it anyway, then it should be done once at program startup.

Comment: @Sasan thanks i already read that in docs i just used it for development purposes and i found the mistake with my code , and i post an answer on the same post here,

Answer (score 0):

i found that class dbContext was not called at all because I didn't inject it with any controller or class

after i inject dbContext to my controller class

```
 [ApiController]
    [Route("/home")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
 private readonly IStorageBroker _storageBrodker;

        public HomeController(IStorageBroker storageBroker)
        {
            _storageBrodker = storageBroker;
        }
```

when i call route /home class is called then migrations apply

i thought it's called because i register it in services
but i didn't know it's called when need to resolve

and the comment for Sasan provide another way to do that from main when build iHost object
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#apply-migrations-at-runtime